# Grabbing web data through IE [c++]

Tags: html, c++, internet-explorer

I'm trying to build a program that functions as a "shell" on top of a lot of web-apps that we're using at work. Instead of individually visit every app, the program will get the information and show it to you.

Unfortunately due to security reasons, some of the apps are only avaliable through IE. Socket programming isn't working here, and I tried various things, but some of the websites wont return any data.
So I figured I need to let the data go through IE. I've found a couple of guides, but nothing functional.

If you now any guides that'd help me get data from a url through IE, or know how to do it, it would be greatly appreciated. One of the pages prints a "Getting data..." and keeps doing that for a few settings, of course the program should wait for this, until it gets the data.

Thanks, and have a great weekend.

Comment: "Due to security reasons, some of the apps are only avaliable through IE". I am pretty sure that this is not a good way of increasing security. What about "WinInet.dll", "shdocvw.dll" and "mshtml.dll" stuff?

Comment: Uhh, can you use IWebbrowser2 interface?